# Basic Matrix Equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Is is true that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and if $A\vec{x}=A\vec{y}$ then $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$? Intuitively this makes sense to me, but I'm just looking for verification or contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

Let $A$ be the zero matrix of size $m \times n$, then we have $Ax= Ay$ for any $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So as long as A is not the zero matrix the equation will hold?

Comment: nope, try to construct counterexample by considering some zero columns. In general, try to think about what is the kernel of $A$.